# LWC - Reset button for the component

Tags: lightning-web-components, button

Hey I have a LWC and want to put a reset button where it can reset everything in the component(such as uploaded files and etc.)

Currently have a retakePhoto function but it seems like it's not working properly. **But** I don't want it to use such function as "**window.location.reload(true);**" where it resets the whole window. Any idea?

This is Demo:
https://webcomponents.dev/edit/spOqm9nMonL1DtibANXA

.html

```
<template>
    <button onclick={startCamera}>Start Camera</button>
    <video width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
    <button onclick={clickPhoto}>Click Photo</button>
    <canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
</template>
```

.js

```
  retakePhoto(event) {
    eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
  }
```

Comment: eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();"); works in lightning experience only. Tough it is throwing exception in https://webcomponents.dev/ it should work in Salesforce.

Comment: Hey @Amit thanks for the comment. Yeah, I've tried that and it totally works. However, it seems that if I'm going through lots of other components, that button resets everything and brings everything to the very front of the list. Do you know how to reset a single LWC? Or giving them a unique ID and allowing them to select which items to reset?

Comment: Nvm found one answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work - Resets the canvas

```
  retakePhoto(event) {
    var canvas = this.template.querySelector('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear html5 canvas
  }
```